# Increase Maximum Heap Size for Java in OSX

Tags: java, macos

This has me stymied --- it should not be!

I would like to increase JAVA heap size in OSX (El Capitan) --- how to go about that?

The LDAP Synchronization Connector (LSC) is a great tool -http://lsc-project.org/wiki/start --- it does not have a JAVA heap size configuration -- I assume it takes what is available from the default.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase heap size in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This is just an hint as I don't know LSC, but you need to find where is the java program called and add or change the heap parameter of the command line (for example -Xms128M).
Try right-clicking on the LSC app, and go to 'Show Package Content' in order to find the script starting the JVM